# XPath Expression to get node with a specific value for child node...namespace agnostic

Tags: xml, xpath

I am needing assistance getting the node that contains a child node with a specific value, namespace agnostic.

So, if this is my XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FWWO xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FWWOSet>
    <WORKORDER>
      <COORDINATES>
        <Point>
          <KEY>123456</KEY>
          <LAT>32.97740936279297</LAT>
          <LONG>-81.84439086914062</LONG>
        </Point>
        <Point>
          <KEY>654321</KEY>
          <LAT>22.932993384764625</LAT>
          <LONG>-66.08171081542969</LONG>
        </Point>
      </COORDINATES>
    </WORKORDER>
  </FWWOSet>
</FWWO>
```

Currently, I can use this

```
//*[name()='Point']
```

and get the following:

```
<Point xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
    <KEY>123456</KEY>
    <LAT>32.97740936279297</LAT>
    <LONG>-81.84439086914062</LONG>
</Point>    
<Point xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
     <KEY>654321</KEY>
     <LAT>22.932993384764625</LAT>
     <LONG>-66.08171081542969</LONG>
</Point>
```

How can I now just get the Point node(and children) that has a KEY node with a value of 654321?

My desired results would be:

```
<Point xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
     <KEY>654321</KEY>
     <LAT>22.932993384764625</LAT>
     <LONG>-66.08171081542969</LONG>
</Point>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an additional predicate...

```
//*[local-name()='Point'][*[local-name()='KEY']='654321']
```

If "*has a node with a value of 654321*" is taken more literally, this is an option...

```
//*[local-name()='Point'][.//node()[contains(.,'654321')]]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.